# Highlight Cell above value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

looking to highlight a cell based on a text criteria.

My file look like this dummy data:

```
Blue 
Yellow 
Red 
Yellow 
Blue 
BLue 
Blue
```

I would like to highlight every cell above the word "Yellow" is there anyway to do this?

Comment: did you check the answer

Comment: yea i ended up using a different method but yours did work.

Comment: Could you show me a screenshot, where its not working, or a link of your workbook so that i can show you at least

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried in this way, follow the steps, first in the adjacent column type the below formula as mentioned** `(Assuming the data is in Column A and starts from cell A1)`

```
=((A1<>"Yellow")*(A2="Yellow"))=1
```

**To check whether it is giving you the expected result as you wanted for,**

**• Copy the formula,**

**• Select the range where you want to conditionally highlight,**

**• From Home Tab, Under Styles Group, Select Conditional Formatting,**

**• Click New,**

**• From New Formatting Rule,**

**• Select the last rule --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format,**

**• Place the above formula in the Edit the Rule Description**

**• Click Format from Fill Tab Choose desired color,**

**• Press Ok Twice and you are done!**

[image: Conditional Formatting]